# Symfony Doctrine select AVG from 4 tables

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm building a system where users can rate books giving scores from 0 to 100. With several ratings, each book gets an average score (example: 88 points from 1423 ratings). Also, in theory I should be able to get a list of authors ordered by the average score of all of the books written by said author (example: an author has written 54 books and the overall average score of the 54 books is 74 points, this is an average score based on the average score of each book).

I don't know if this is too confusing for you, so I'll show you my tables:

- User: id, other data
- Book: id, other data
- Author: id, other data
- Rating: user_id, book_id, score, other data
- Authors: book_id, author_id, other data

So User, Book and Author are single entities. Rating and Authors are mid-tables used to relate the single entities (a book could recieve multiple ratings and a book could be written by multiple authors). User isn't actually required for what I'm asking, but I wanted to show you, so you can understand better.

So finally, if I want to retrieve an author list ordered by the global average score of all of the books written by each author, how should I write the query in Symfony Doctrine?

I suspect I'll need at least 3 inner joins, but I can't figure this one out.

EDIT: solution found

After rethinking the problem, I reaches the conclusion that I don't need to do an average of other averages, I should just do an average of all the ratings of all of the author's books. With this neaw approach, I only need 3 tables to execute my query:

```
SELECT AVG(Rating.score) FROM Rating, Author, Authors WHERE Rating.book_id = Authors.book_id AND Authors.author_id = Author.id AND Author.id = $author_id;
```

Parsing this to Doctrine works perfectly (changing column names with entity fields obviously).

Comment: Specifically what have you done so far to try and fix your problem?

Comment: I've written 4 or 5 versions of the method in the Repository, but all of them either return syntax error or incorrect information (because the query wasn't build in the right way). I believe this is a simple question, but I couldn't find anything in Google or the Doctrine manual. Trying to input actual MySql into doctrine doesn't work, as Doctrine has its own methods and rules. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: If you're curious, I tried to write a query with multiple select. Something like : SELECT * FROM (SELECT id FROM(SELECT x FROM)) and so on, but it says "(" isn't any class, so I guess that will not work with Doctrine :(

Comment: You can add an answer and accept it, if you can't now you'll have to wait a little.

Comment: Do I need to mark my own answer?